# Pass array to Flot chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, flot

As we know normally we can pass array as following to Flot Aria Chart.

```
var data2 = [
        [0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 0], [4, 1], [5, 3], [6, 1], [7, 5], [8, 2], [9, 3], [10, 2], [11, 1], [12, 0], [13, 2], [14, 8], [15, 0], [16, 0]
    ];
```

I'm getting an json output from a file and i need to convert that as json object like 'data2' in upper code. i'm running a loop like this.

```
var data1 = [];
    var json = $.getJSON( "config/tsconfig.json", function () {
        $.each( json.responseJSON, function( i, item ) {

        });
    });
```

And inside of that json file like this.

```
[[2,"2017-09-27",50,30,25],[2,"2017-09-28",70,50,49],[3,"2017-09-27",50,45,5],[3,"2017-09-28",100,95,90]]
```

How can i make a json object as in code one. any suggestions to put inside $.each loop?

Comment: what does your json looks like ?

Comment: I just put it on question.

Comment: What represents the first array ?

Comment: What is the output for your json ?

Comment: Oh. forgot my silliness. array[0][0]=campaign_id,  array[0][1]=date, array[0][2]=total count, array[0][3]=responded count, array[0][4]=correct count

As in first code 'data2' i need to create an array like that with array[0][2] in this json file

Comment: Please provide numbers.

Comment: You mentioned in answer that you need data like `data2`.

Comment: As in first code 'data2' i need to create an array like that with value of array[0][2]

Comment: Is this the array you want  `[[0, 50], [1, 70], [2, 50], [3, 100]]` ?

Comment: @LahiruMadusanka, have a look to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `map` method.

Also, `$.getJSON` is executing `asynchronous`, so you need to use a `callback` function.

```
getResponse(callback){
    $.getJSON( "config/tsconfig.json", function (response) {
      let result=response.map(function(item){
         return [item[0],item[2]];
       });
       callback(result);
    });
}

getResponse(function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

```js
let array=[[2,"2017-09-27",50,30,25],[2,"2017-09-28",70,50,49],[3,"2017-09-27",50,45,5],[3,"2017-09-28",100,95,90]]
array=array.map(function(item){
  return [item[0],item[2]];
});
console.log(array);
```

Using `arrow` **functions**.

```
array=array.map(item=> [item[0],item[2]]);
```

Comment: json.responseJSON is array i'm getting. how can i place your code in it?

var json = $.getJSON( "config/tsconfig.json", function () {
            console.log(json.responseJSON);
            });
        });

Comment: @LahiruMadusanka, have a look now.

Comment: no its not working.. :(
can't access lexical declaration `json' before initialization

Comment: @LahiruMadusanka, where before ?

Comment: How can i call json out side of the getJSON?

Comment: @LahiruMadusanka, for this you have to use a `callback` function.

Comment: How can i do that? can you please help me.

Comment: @LahiruMadusanka, have a look now to updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155509/discussion-between-lahiru-madusanka-and-alexandru-ionut-mihai).